Problem with building the generated ino file from ppt
I'm using PowerPoint_to_sketch powerpoint macro to generate ino files from a presentation file.
Here is the problem. After complying with the rules listed at the first sample style, the ino file has been successfully autogenerated, BUT after trying to compile the file for ESP32 and a 320x240 TFT+touch display connected to it, there are some errors that I don't know how to solve. ( I'm sure that TFT_eSPI lib is configured correctly.)
Here is the error:


Indexing .pio\build\esp32doit-devkit-v1\lib37e\libTFT_eSPI.a
src/main.cpp:31:33: error: no matching function for call to 'TFT_eSPI_ext::TFT_eSPI_ext()'
 TFT_eSPI_ext tft = TFT_eSPI_ext();
                                 ^
In file included from lib/PowerPoint_to_sketch/ILI9341_t3.h:2,
                 from lib/PowerPoint_to_sketch/font_Arial.h:4,
                 from src/main.cpp:24:
lib/PowerPoint_to_sketch/TFT_eSPI_ext.h:36:3: note: candidate: 'TFT_eSPI_ext::TFT_eSPI_ext(TFT_eSPI*)'
   TFT_eSPI_ext(TFT_eSPI *tft)
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~
lib/PowerPoint_to_sketch/TFT_eSPI_ext.h:36:3: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
lib/PowerPoint_to_sketch/TFT_eSPI_ext.h:29:7: note: candidate: 'TFT_eSPI_ext::TFT_eSPI_ext(const TFT_eSPI_ext&)'
 class TFT_eSPI_ext : public TFT_eSPI
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~
lib/PowerPoint_to_sketch/TFT_eSPI_ext.h:29:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
src/main.cpp: In function 'void setup()':
src/main.cpp:75:44: warning: unsigned conversion from 'int' to 'uint16_t' {aka 'short unsigned int'} changes value from '65536' to '0' [-Woverflow]
   Button4.initButton(&tft,154, 54, 222, 5, 0x10000, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, buttonLabel4, 2);
                                            ^~~~~~~
src/main.cpp:76:46: warning: unsigned conversion from 'int' to 'uint16_t' {aka 'short unsigned int'} changes value from '65536' to '0' [-Woverflow]
   Button5.initButton(&tft,154, 112, 193, 31, 0x10000, 0xC2C2, 0xFFFF, buttonLabel5, 2);
                                              ^~~~~~~
src/main.cpp:77:46: warning: unsigned conversion from 'int' to 'uint16_t' {aka 'short unsigned int'} changes value from '65536' to '0' [-Woverflow]
   Button6.initButton(&tft,154, 168, 193, 31, 0x10000, 0xC2C2, 0xFFFF, buttonLabel6, 2);
                                              ^~~~~~~
src/main.cpp:78:44: warning: unsigned conversion from 'int' to 'uint16_t' {aka 'short unsigned int'} changes value from '65536' to '0' [-Woverflow]
   Button7.initButton(&tft,294, 24, 37, 35, 0x10000, 0xF800, 0xFFFF, buttonLabel7, 2);
                                            ^~~~~~~
src/main.cpp:79:45: warning: unsigned conversion from 'int' to 'uint16_t' {aka 'short unsigned int'} changes value from '65536' to '0' [-Woverflow]
   Button8.initButton(&tft,93, 110, 110, 31, 0x10000, 0xC2C2, 0xFFFF, buttonLabel8, 2);
                                             ^~~~~~~
src/main.cpp:80:46: warning: unsigned conversion from 'int' to 'uint16_t' {aka 'short unsigned int'} changes value from '65536' to '0' [-Woverflow]
   Button9.initButton(&tft,215, 112, 110, 31, 0x10000, 0xC2C2, 0xFFFF, buttonLabel9, 2);
                                              ^~~~~~~
src/main.cpp:81:46: warning: unsigned conversion from 'int' to 'uint16_t' {aka 'short unsigned int'} changes value from '65536' to '0' [-Woverflow]
   Button10.initButton(&tft,93, 170, 110, 31, 0x10000, 0xC2C2, 0xFFFF, buttonLabel10, 2);
                                              ^~~~~~~
src/main.cpp:82:47: warning: unsigned conversion from 'int' to 'uint16_t' {aka 'short unsigned int'} changes value from '65536' to '0' [-Woverflow]
   Button11.initButton(&tft,215, 170, 110, 31, 0x10000, 0xC2C2, 0xFFFF, buttonLabel11, 2);
                                               ^~~~~~~
src/main.cpp:83:45: warning: unsigned conversion from 'int' to 'uint16_t' {aka 'short unsigned int'} changes value from '65536' to '0' [-Woverflow]
   Button12.initButton(&tft,154, 54, 222, 5, 0x10000, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, buttonLabel12, 2);
                                             ^~~~~~~
src/main.cpp:84:45: warning: unsigned conversion from 'int' to 'uint16_t' {aka 'short unsigned int'} changes value from '65536' to '0' [-Woverflow]
   Button13.initButton(&tft,294, 24, 37, 35, 0x10000, 0xF800, 0xFFFF, buttonLabel13, 2);
                                             ^~~~~~~
src/main.cpp: In function 'void loop()':
src/main.cpp:92:3: error: 'Screen1' was not declared in this scope
   Screen1();
   ^~~~~~~
src/main.cpp:92:3: note: suggested alternative: '_reent'
   Screen1();
   ^~~~~~~
   _reent
src/main.cpp:97:3: error: 'Screen2' was not declared in this scope
   Screen2();
   ^~~~~~~
src/main.cpp:97:3: note: suggested alternative: '_reent'
   Screen2();
   ^~~~~~~
   _reent
src/main.cpp:102:3: error: 'Screen3' was not declared in this scope
   Screen3();
   ^~~~~~~
src/main.cpp:102:3: note: suggested alternative: '_reent'
   Screen3();
   ^~~~~~~
   _reent
Compiling .pio\build\esp32doit-devkit-v1\libc11\PowerPoint_to_sketch\font_ArialBold.c.o
*** [.pio\build\esp32doit-devkit-v1\src\main.cpp.o] Error 1


and here is a piece of my code providing some information:
#include <font_Arial.h>
#include <font_ArialBold.h>
#include <font_ArialItalic.h>
#include <font_ArialBoldItalic.h>

#include <SPI.h>
#include <TFT_eSPI_ext.h>
TFT_eSPI_ext tft = TFT_eSPI_ext();

In this repo, all needed headers can be found: TFT_eSPI_ext

It seems that TFT_eSPI_ext is a class without a default constructor. And that its construction needs a TFT_eSPI* argument which you do not provide.

If you looked at the examples for guidance, they are broken - the constructor needs a pointer to a TFT_eSPI, as in TFT_eSPI base; TFT_eSPI_ext extension(&base);.

@Someprogrammerdude it's appended.

@molbdnilo I have tried that before, but some weird errors happened consequently. there is a function defined under class in the header, but in the main, the compiler could not resolve that even after cleaning and rebuilding.

All in all, that "PowerPoint to sketch" application seems to not create working code. Besides the TFT_eSPI_ext error, it tries to use values that are too large for the types used. And it doesn't declare the functions it generates before they are called. You need to do a lot of manual labor to make the code work.

It is very difficult to understand what "a function defined under class in the header" refers to.

The problem's been solved.
I just replaced
TFT_eSPI_ext tft = TFT_eSPI_ext();

By
TFT_eSPI tftExt; // Create the base TFT_eSPI instance
TFT_eSPI_ext tft(&tftExt); // Pass a pointer to the base instance

Also declarations of Screens after directives and before the setup function were added and everything works now.
